# Automatically Deploy latest release on virtual machine startup

Tags: azure-devops

We are creating multiple Linux virtual machines and deploying code using deployment group (VSTS).

We are creating a separate virtual machine for a new client that time we have configured the events that trigger automated redeployment on the new target.

We also stop the virtual machine of a client whose work is done so we can optimise the cost.

But when we start client’s virtual machine again that time we have to pull/deploy the latest released code on that machine. Because code which is deployed on that virtual machine can be old version.

Is there any way or functionality on VSTS which can help me out for this problem?

Comment: You can create a task on start up, is that ok ?

Comment: @AmitBaranes No, that will not work.